# XML Parsing failed

Tags: .net, xml, xml-parsing

I have this in a XML doc.

```
<userdata name='filter'>&SearchExpression[0].Key=Id&SearchExpression[0].Value=1&</userdata>
```

The value is a query which will be added to an url.

It keeps failing to parse. It says the document isn't well formatted. The parser is pointing at the bracket "["

Could the bracket causing the error ?

How can I parse a XML file with a bracket ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your xml to this:

```
<userdata name='filter'><![CDATA[&SearchExpression[0].Key=Id&SearchExpression[0].Value=1&]]></userdata>
```

It means the same, but allows you to have special characters in the element inner text.
You can read more about CDATA [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's *actually* due to the ampersands. Ampersands need to be escaped in XML, as `&amp;`. Your XML should be:

```
<userdata name='filter'>&amp;SearchExpression[0].Key=Id&amp;[...]</userdata>
```

My guess is that it gave an error at `[` because it was expecting a semi-colon, thinking that `SearchExpression` was an entity name (which can't include `[`).

Was this document hand-edited, or created by a program? If it was autogenerated (and it was your code) then you should start using XML APIs to create the XML, rather than manually writing out strings - they handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the unfinished escape sequences starting with `&` you need to either wrap the element content in `<![CDATA[  ]]>`, or escape the `&` thus: `&amp;`